# Deciding how to partition your backup keys on a GridGain cluster

Tags: partitioning, gridgain

From the GridGain documentation I can see that through the annotation @GridCacheAffinityKeyMapped I can collocate cache entries with the same field marked by @GridCacheAffinityKeyMapped, such as all records by the same user.

1) What happens if, for example, I annotate "String username" with @GridCacheAffinityKeyMapped and I have a cluster such that each node can only hold X records, but I choose to store Z records with the same username field. Would an eviction policy (assuming I had a simple FIFO policy limiting each node to hold X records) cause me to lose (Z - X) records and thus storing all records with the same username on the same node or would the records be partitioned across two different nodes?

2) Is there a way for me to specify where the backups are mapped? For resiliency purposes, I would like to control where the backups are.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unless you configure `synchronized evictions`, the eviction policy is local to each node. So in your example, (Z - X) records will be evicted. By the way, `@GridCacheAffinityKeyMapped` annotation plays no difference here.
2. Yes, you can override affinity mapping by providing your own `GridCacheAffinityFunction` in cache configuration. However, take a look at `GridCacheConsistentHashAffinityFunction.setBackupFilter(...)` or `GridCacheRendezvousAffinityFunction.setBackupFilter(...)` methods. These methods allow you to control which nodes are mapped to backups.